# "SHARE" menu on right top of instant article

Tags: facebook, facebook-instant-articles

We are implementing facebook instant articles by RSS feed and testing it in the development feed. I saw instant articles, however for each article in instant view, I want add more options to top “SHARE” menu, is it configurable? For example I want to add “Share Now”, “twitter, "email",.., how do I configure them. Or do I have to code them and send over through the feed?

Comment: That Facebook does not actively encourage users to share in other social networks such as Twitter, seems only natural, no …?

Answer (score 0):

These options can't be configured for
an Instant Article

Comment: then do you know how to implement them?

Comment: Well, as I said, you can't customize the Share menu in the upper right corner of the app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about that but you can add share and like buttons to any single image using

```
<figure data-feedback="fb:likes, fb:comments">
    <img src="/path/to/img.jpg" />
</figure>
```

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/reference/image

Comment: He is asking for the Share button the Facebook app shows in the upper right corner when viewing an Instant Article